# How to calculate variance given weights and co-variance matrix

Tags: statistics

### Inputs:

1. Co-variance matrix of stocks.

For example, the co-variance between IBM / FB is 0.1, co-variance IBM / Wells Fargo is 1, co-variance between Wells Fargo / 0.2 etc etc etc

2. Weights

I have 30% of my portfolio in IBM and 50% in FB and 20% in Wells Fargo

### Question:

How do I calculate variance of the overall portfolio

Comment: Letting $(\sigma_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^n$ be the covariance matrix, then the variance is $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j\sigma_{i,j}$. This summation can be simplified a bit, since there are repeats; you need to add up the values of $x_{i}^2\sigma_{ii}^2$ for each $i$ (note $\sigma_{ii}^2$ is the variance of the $i^\text{th}$ stock) and then add up $2x_ix_j\sigma_{ij}$ for each pair $i<j$.

Comment: Can you include an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Letting $x_i$ be the weight of the $i$th stock, so $\sum_i x_i=1$, and letting $(\sigma_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ be the covariance matrix, then the variance of the portfolio is $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_ix_jσ_{ij}.\tag1$$

This summation can be simplified a bit, since there are repeats; you need to add up the values of $x^2_i\sigma^2_{ii}$ for each $i$ (note $\sigma^2_{ii}$ is the variance of the $i^\text{th}$ stock) and then add up $2x_ix_jσ_{ij}$ for each pair $i<j$.

The reason for this is that if $R$ is the return of the portfolio, and $R_i$ is the return of the $i$th stock, then
$$
R=\sum_i x_iR_i
$$
so
$$
Var(R)=Var(\sum_i x_iR_i)
$$
Now, use the rule for the variance of a sum:
$$
Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)
$$
Doing this repeatedly leads to the expression (1).

Comment: And does x represent the weight? Can you specify the notation in your answer?

Comment: And if possible could you also explain a little behind this formula? Why is it the multiplying the weights?

Comment: I can provide more details, just not for a day or two.